# Multiprocessing in Python - process does not stop after pool.join()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have written a simple piece of code to speed up my function f, an example using 2 CPUs is shown below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes = 2)   
    f0_list = pool.map(f,range(nlocs))
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
    final_f0 = np.sum(f0_list,axis=0)

f0_final = final_f0[0:121] # here I get the error message: 'final_f0 not defined'
```

My result 'final_f0' is correct. However, I was expecting that, after pool.join(), all processes would end which does not seem to be the case, because:

1. I still have one CPU running in the background and it does not seem to stop even though final_f0 has been effectively returned?
2. When I try to cut 'final_f0' as described above, I get this error message. The error message prints many times as if Python was running the script over and over again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You say you have one CPU running in the background - are you sure the CPU usages is actually caused by a Python process? `pool.terminate()` kills all the processes in your pool before you even call `join` on it. As for #2, we'd need to see more code, and the actual tracebacks you're getting, to help.

Comment: Yes I pretty sure it is Python, as I stopped every other program running on my machine to check. As for my operation on f0_final, it is pretty simple I am just trying to keep only the first 122 values - I updated my question above with some more details.

Comment: Are you using Windows? You should be able to check the task manager to see *exactly* what process is using the CPU, and also to see if there are actually multiple python processes running after you terminate the pool.

Comment: Yes, so in Windows when I check the 'processes' in the task manager I have 'python.exe 32' using CPU as well as 'System Idle process'. Not sure what that is... the CPU column for python 32 goes from 0 to 25 and the pattern repeats. And as I said my run in Spyder is finished as I can plot my results etc. I dont understand...

Comment: If you only have one python process running, that suggests your pool *is* shut down, since you've got two processes in the pool. Also, is the indentation in your example code *exactly* the same as your real program? Particularly the last line?

Comment: Actually you are right: for the second problem, I had the wrong indent which is why I couldn't access 'final_f0'. So this problem is solved!

Comment: Cool. I converted that comment into an answer with some more explanation about what's actually happening there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error about `f0_final` because you didn't keep that line inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard. On Windows, `multiprocessing` needs to re-import your `__main__` module in the child processes it spawns, which means everything at the top level of your module will get executed in both the parent process *and* all of its children.

The line

```
f0_final = final_f0[0:121]
```

is defined at the top level of the module, so it gets executed in all your child processes, however, the code under the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard does not, so your attempt to take a slice of `final_f0` will fail, which means all the child processes will fail. This will keep your main process from getting the results of the `map` call back, and prevent the pool from being properly shut down.